# Unity3D (5.1) NavMesh Agent Error

Tags: unity, navmesh

This is my first post in GameDev StackExchange, so please excuse me if I make any mistakes on best practices here (if I do, please refer me so I can learn).

I'm making a prototype where I have 2 types of enemy units: Uninfected and Infected. The Uninfected are to seek out Infected via AI pathfinding. However, I came across an issue when implementing the NavMesh in the scene. If the Player collides with an Uninfected, they go flying backwards. If they hit the walls, the walls collectively get hit. Here's some screenshots.

Example 1:
http://s7.photobucket.com/user/Korudo/media/GameDev/RoboInfect%20Scene%20-%20WallWeirdness1_zpsg0k2wbyk.png.html

Example 2:
http://s7.photobucket.com/user/Korudo/media/GameDev/RoboInfect%20Scene%20-%20WallWeirdness1_zpsg0k2wbyk.png.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be great if you could include the pictures in the post body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what u tried and what exactly could be your problem but I would suggest you check if all the navmesh is baked properly and you could also change a few things in NavMeshAgent properties and see if it gets fixed. You could also prevent collision between navmesh agent and the player via NavMeshAgent properties or scripting.